# Spring OAuth2 ClientId passed in as username for password grant type

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, xml-configuration

I am attempting a very basic implementation of the Spring OAuth2 library; however, when I send a request off to the server I receive the following error:

```
{
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "Bad client credentials"
}
```

When doing further debugging, I notice that for some reason the clientId is being passed in as the username within the resource owner flow.

I have included my XML configuration and am curious if anyone could tell me if anything seems inherently wrong or if anyone has any suggestions.

```
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetailsService" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>

<authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" token-services-ref="tokenServices" >
    <authorization-code />
    <implicit />
    <refresh-token />
    <client-credentials />
    <password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
</authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceFilter" token-services-ref="tokenServices" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />

<security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <security:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<client-details-service id="clientDetailsService"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2">
    <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        scope="read,write,trust" resource-ids="oauth2-resource"
        access-token-validity="60" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
        redirect-uri="http://anywhere" />
    <oauth:client client-id="my-client-with-registered-redirect"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code" scope="read,trust"
        resource-ids="oauth2-resource" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"
        redirect-uri="http://anywhere?key=value" />
    <oauth:client client-id="my-client-with-secret" secret="secret"
        authorized-grant-types="password,client_credentials" scope="read"
        resource-ids="oauth2-resource" access-token-validity="60"
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" />
</client-details-service>
```

Bellow is also the request that I am sending to the server, it is encoded as 'x-www-form-urlencoded'

```
grant_type:password
client_id:my-client-with-secret
client_secret:secret
username:user
password:password
scope:read write
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from here:

```
<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>
```

I am passing the user authentication manager rather than a client details authentication manager. Had to create an additional bean that is of type ClientDetailsAuthenticationManager and pass that within the ref.